# Neural network XOR backpropagation info needed

Tags: c++, matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

Does anyone know where I can find some sample codes about the NN Back propagation for `XOR`,
that I can also test the system after it was trained?

Preferably in C++ or MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend ['Step by Step Guide to Implementing a Neural Network in C'](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~jxb/NN/nn.html) by  John A. Bullinaria.

This is very simple walk through on how to implement a multi-layer neural network that's capable of learning how to XOR.

The code introduced in the article is in C, which is very easy to understand. Most 'introduction-to-neural-network' articles on the web are Object-Oriented-based and comes in form of reusable libraries, which may make them harder to be understood and get started with.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten a few answers dealing with C code, so here's [an XOR demo for MATLAB](http://www-cs.ccny.cuny.edu/~csolb/CscI1900/xor.htm). The demo is written for an older version of MATLAB (ver. 6) and requires the [Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neuralnet/), but should hopefully still give you some ideas on how to implement the network.

**EDIT:** For more general information on backpropagation algorithms in the Neural Network Toolbox, I would suggest the [online documentation at The MathWorks website](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/nnet/backprop.html).

Comment: nice to hear from you again gnovice, i'd like to know if there are any tutorial just for backp ropagation? without XOR..

Comment: Yup, just added a link for the online documentation. =)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163573/xor-with-neural-networks-matlab), that I think is really really simple. Oh what the hell. I'll just repost the code here.

```
function layer2 = xornn2(iters)
    if nargin < 1
        iters = 50
    end
    T = [0 1 1 0];
    X = [0 0 1 1; 0 1 0 1; 1 1 1 1];
    m = size(T,2);
    inputsz = size(X,1)-1;
    hiddensz = 3;
    outputsz = size(T,1);
    theta1 = randn(hiddensz, 1+inputsz);
    theta2 = randn(outputsz, 1+hiddensz);
    for i = [1:iters]
        layer1 = [logsig(theta1 * X); ones(1,m)];
        layer2 = logsig(theta2 * layer1);
        delta2 = T - layer2;
        delta1 = layer1 .* (1-layer1) .* (theta2' * delta2);
        % remove the bias from delta 1. There's no real point in a delta on the bias.
        delta1 = delta1(1:(end-1),:);
        theta2d = delta2 * layer1';
        theta1d = delta1 * X';
        theta1 = theta1 + 0.1 * theta1d;
        theta2 = theta2 + 0.1 * theta2d;
    end
end
```

The random initialization can be improved upon. (I'd make it sqrt(6./(fanin+fanout))... (That's from a paper from Yoshua Bengio..) But, it basically works.. Try it with xornn(10000) for instance. You should be able to change hiddensz to anything >= 2.